# response.redirect() with parameters

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, request-response

I want to redirect to a page where the path is like /users/home/:id

```
   response.redirect('/users/home')
```

The above code will redirect to /users/home but I want to redirect it to a page like '/users/home/1' dynamically with parameters. How shall I solve it?Do explain with some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use template literals to form the new url, for example:

```
app.get("/users/home/:id", (req, res) => { 
    res.redirect(`/users/alternate_home/${req.params.id}`);
});

app.get("/users/alternate_home/:id", (req, res) => { 
    res.json(users);
});
```